# Fastest way to sort and concatenate million or billion STL vectors

Tags: c++, vector

What is the best way to sort and concatenate million or billion STL vectors into a single STL vector. Presently, the way I am doing it is to just iterate over the vectors and perform each operation.

Here is the pseudo code

```
typedef unsigned long long int ULLInt;

ULLInt N = 1000000;

vector<vector<ULLInt> > vecVec( N, vector<ULLInt>() );
vector<ULLInt>          concatVec;

// ...
// ... fill vectors inside vecVec here 
// ..  we also get here the total number of values inserted in all vectors (count)
// ...

// reserve the space
concatVec.reserve( count);

// sort each vector and concatenate them in sequence
for( ULLInt i=0; i<N; i++)
  sort( vecVec[i].begin(), vecVec[i].end() );
  concatVec.insert( concatVec.end(), vecVec[i].begin(), vecVec[i].end() );
end for
```

Note that there is no requirement for concatVec to be sorted. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You're going to need a lot of memory if these vectors aren't empty. Possibly check out `std::merge` if you want the end result to be sorted as well.

Comment: There's [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge), but I'm not sure if it can be used in-place.

Comment: Oh, no, you can't use `std::merge`: "The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges."

Comment: Yes, those vectors are filled. I am working on a 16GB machine with 16 processor cores. I know I could employ some sort of loop level parallelism, but I am curious to see other ways of doing it.

Comment: shouldn't you be using some ordered node based container?

Comment: @Kerrek SB You can possibly use `std::inplace_merge` though.

Comment: @MarkB: Yes, indeed! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: 1. From your pseudocode - mergedVec is not sorted, is it intention? 2. What is your aim? Do you need individual sorted vectors in vecVec, or you need just sorted mergedVec ?

Comment: @John: Yes, there is no use case for mergedVec to be sorted.

Comment: If mergedVec is not required to be sorted, then you don't need nor std::merge nor std::inplace_merge.

Comment: @John: I need individually sorted vectors to be merged in vecMerged.

Comment: sorry, "merge" is confusive here. Maybe better to use "concatenation"?

Comment: Are vectors in vecVec filled in ascending order? If yes, maybe you want to place them directly into the mergedVec, and having separate vector with indices where each subvector begin and ends. Later you may sort sub-vectors individualy.

Comment: @John: sorry for the typo. Actually hstVecVec was vecVec vector. I have fixed the typo. I understand your suggestion about indices, but isn't just that some extra overhead as eventually we will still be sorting each sub-vector iteratively.

Comment: You have to sort each sub_vector in any case. I am offering to avoid expensive concatination, by "constructing" vectors in place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15347/discussion-between-nurav-and-john)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

- Split the vectors into *cores* piles. Calculate the size needed for each pile
- Reserve space in a vector for all the data
- Split this vector into *cores* parts.
- Feed the parts and the piles to a thread for merging.

some quick code (prob. won't compile but you might get the point):

```
typedef vector<vector<ULLINT>> ManyVectors; 

void merge(ManyVectors vector_of_vectors) {
  const int cores = 16;
  std::array<ManyVectors, cores> piles = split_vector(vector_of_vectors,cores);
  std::array<size_t, cores> sizes = calculate_sizes(piles,cores);
  std::vector<ULLINT> result;
  result.reserve(sum_of_sizes(sizes));
  int used = 0; 
  int core = 0;
  for (ManyVectors& pile: piles) {
    std::thread(merge_vectors, pile, result.begin()+used);
    used += sizes[core];
    core += 1;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by cores, piles and parts. Its confusing.

Comment: @nurav check edits, just ask if my code is completely unreadable

Answer (score 3):

One thing I'd do is ask if you really need to concatentate a million std::vectors.  What if you added each vector to a list and made your own iterator that would traverse each element in each vector?  For most algorithms, that would be indistinguishable from one massive vector.  And, depending on the load, the extra work done in the custom iterator would be far less than all the work needed to actually concatenate all the vectors.

Comment: Actually I need to eventually copy the concatenated data on a GPU. For gpu's any pointer chasing data is not suitable.

Comment: I used flat arrays of data, with separate array of indices for computing SPMV on GPU (using OpenCL). I used CSR ("Compressed Sparse Row") format for sparse matrix. It works pretty well.

Comment: My idea is the same. I actually have to read sparse graph data (which is equivalent to a square sparse matrix) from a file and because some sizes are not available even at runtime, I cannot allocate memory upfront. So I have to resort to dynamic structures. Vectors are better than lists in terms of locality, but have overheads of resizes and data copying. Actually I think making vector of dequeues is better than vector of vectors because dequeue combines properties of a linked list and a vector. I am evaluating which approach is good.

Comment: First of all, consider using boost::container::deque - I remember that it outperformed MSVC std::deque. Second, realocations and recopying in fact may be faster than sorting deques (just imagine how RANDOM access works for deque - there at least one additional level of indirection). It will be only ln(N) realocations. And third, you may try to reserve much of RAM - GPU's in typical have much less RAM than in main memory. Also, you may try to determe size of total data with heuristic, for instance based on input filesize.

Comment: Actually I had made a cache blocked linked list which does sorted insertion while filling the list. I used a heuristics of 8 elements per block. As the graph is sparse, the number of reallocations are not so many. Also the sorted insert works well for small sizes. Just to give you an idea, for a sparse graph with 4 million vertices and 16million edges, I am able to create my graph data structure in less than 4 secs. As I saw on the internet, implementation of dequeue is very much similar to a cache blocked linked list except that it has no sorted insertion function.

Comment: For vector-vector approach, another idea is to upfront allocate some memory(say 8) for each sub-vector. Again as the graph is sparse, I think the re-allocations will be very much lesser. Albeit, there is always some memory wastage when some sub-vectors donot get completely filled. But the heuristic can be tuned to keep memory wastage under check.

Comment: yes, implementation of deque is something simmilar to blocked linked list. Check following code: http://ideone.com/4nAnl, MSVC2010 x64 "Total" results: std::vector 0.71s, std::deque 2.39s, boost::container::deque 1.08s http://ideone.com/Rbx0A

Comment: Let's do some calculations on results. (boost::deque::sort_time - std::vector::sort_time)/std::vector::assign_time = 18 . It means, in that benchmark, you may do 18 additional FULL realocations (growing vector realocations are not full - they are much less) of std::vector until it will take same time to FAST deque implementation.

Comment: i.e., in that case, slower sorting of deque is much bigger issue than vector realocations.

Comment: Another version - http://ideone.com/KPCWw , here I do element-by-element push_back. Results: http://ideone.com/eIztZ . Despite filling of std::vector is slower (due to realocations) than boost::container::deque, total time is still much better for std::vector

Answer (score 1):

Each time the code inserts the contents of one of the vectors it has to make sure the target vector has enough memory to hold the result. This means that it will frequently reallocate the memory for the target vector. That means copying its contents, and the code ends up doing that many, many times. It will be **much** faster to pre-allocate the memory for the target vector to the eventual full size. Read about `vector::reserve()`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that multiple reallocations might fragment the heap to the point where one of the larger reallocations fails, even though allocating the full amount at the start would have succeeded.

Comment: sorry, actually I am already doing it. I forgot to mention in pseudo code. I will just correct the code.

Answer (score 1):

If vectors in vecVec are filled in ascending order(as I understand from chat - that is the your use case), then you may try to use one vector instead of many smalls, maintaining begin index of each vector in separate indices array.
That will avoid expensive concatination, by "constructing" sub-vectors in place.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    typedef int Payload;
    vector<Payload> vec;
    vector<size_t> indices;
    for(unsigned i=0;i!=100;++i)
    {
        indices.push_back(vec.size()); // begin index of current vector
        // filling current sub-vector
        generate_n(back_inserter(vec),777+i,rand);
    }
    indices.push_back(vec.size()); // end of last vector, or begin of
                                   // one-past last vector

    // sorting each sub vector
    for(size_t i=0;i+1!=indices.size();++i)
    {
        // can be done in parallel. be aware of possible false sharing
        sort(vec.begin()+indices[i],vec.begin()+indices[i+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```